# find F-statistic using R output

Tags: r, regression, f-statistic

I have this R output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mortaliteit ~ rokers)
Residuals:
30
Min      1Q     Median  3Q     Max
-30.369 -18.685 3.116   13.988 31.450
Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std.Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -2.4983    23.4971    -0.106   0.916
rokers       1.0866    0.2252     4.825    ????? ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1 1
Residual standard error: 18.97 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.5142, Adjusted R-squared: 0.4921
F-statistic: ???? on 1 and 22 DF, p-value: ??????
```

I need to find the correct values of the F-statistic and the corresponding p-value. How can I do this using this output?

I know $F = SSR/SSE$ but I don't know how to get these values out of the given R output, and I don't have the ANOVA output.

Comment: Is this an school assignment or did this output come directly from an R session?  I'm asking because I'm trying to understand why you have question marks in certain places in your output.  If this is an assignment, then I'd suggest you mark this with the self-study tag and begin by looking up the relationship between a t-statistic and an F-statistic.

Comment: Another hint: look for the relationship between $R^2$ and $F$-statistic.